# Downcase email address and creating MD5 sum before saving it

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an `Email` model which stores e-mail addresses. Before saving it I'd like to downcase the `value`. Plus I'd like to create an MD5 sum of it and save it in `md5sum`. What is the cleanest way to do this in Phoenix?

**web/models/email.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Email do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "emails" do
    field :value, :string
    field :md5sum, :string

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(value)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried? It would be easier to help you knowing what you tried and failed to make work.

Comment: I'm still mentally stuck in the Rails world and search for a callback function.

Comment: @wintermeyer Callbacks are evil, you wont get far with them if you are planning on creating something supportable in the long run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would create 2 functions and pipe through them in `changeset`:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> downcase_value
  |> fill_md5sum
end

def downcase_value(changeset) do
  update_change(changeset, :value, &String.downcase/1)
end

def fill_md5sum(changeset) do
  if value = get_change(changeset, :value) do
    md5sum = :crypto.hash(:md5, value)
    put_change(changeset, :md5sum, md5sum)
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> changeset = Email.changeset(%Email{}, %{value: "FOO@EXAMPLE.COM"})
iex(2)> changeset.changes
%{md5sum: <<180, 141, 239, 100, 87, 88, 185, 85, 55, 212, 66, 76, 132, 209, 169, 255>>,
  value: "foo@example.com"}
```

Comment: For those who are using it to get a downcased MD5 sum: `md5sum = :crypto.hash(:md5, value) |> Base.encode16 |> String.downcase`

Comment: For the downcasing function, you can use `Ecto.Changeset.update_change/3` instead.

Comment: @wintermeyer you can also do `|> Base.encode16(case: :lower)` and skip `String.downcase`.

Comment: @michalmuskala thank you. I did not know about that function. I've edited my answer to use it. :)